# CherryPy: Turn off tool for one handler

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a class with several routes and I'd like them to all use the json tools *except for one*.  How can I exclude a specific route from a tool (`foo` in the example below)?

```
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld(object):
    _cp_config = {
        'tools.json_out.on': True,
        'tools.json_in.on': True,
        '/foo': {
           'tools.json_out.on': True,
           'tools.json_in.on': True
        }
    }
    @cherrypy.expose()
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"
    @cherrypy.expose()
    def foo(self):
        return "Hello World!"

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with the `cherrypy.config` decorator:

```
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld(object):
    _cp_config = {
        'tools.json_out.on': True,
        'tools.json_in.on': True
    }

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"

    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.config(**{'tools.json_in.on': False, 'tools.json_out.on': False})
    def foo(self):
        return "Hello World!"

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, but equivalent, approach to @cyraxjoe's answer is

```
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld(object):
    _cp_config = {
        'tools.json_out.on': True,
        'tools.json_in.on': True
    }

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"

    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.config(**{'tools.json_in.on': False, 'tools.json_out.on': False})
    def foo(self):
        return "Hello World!"
    foo._cp_config = {
        'tools.json_out.on': False,
        'tools.json_in.on': False,
    }

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```